# Proving $|S \times \mathbb{N}|=|S|$ when $S$ is an infinite set

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I am trying to prove that, given a collection $\{S_i:i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ of infinite sets which all have the same cardinality, that $|S_1 \cup S_2 \cup \cdots|=|S_1|$. WLOG, I'm going to assume the $S_i$ are disjoint.

My thought was to let each $f_i:S_1 \to S_i$ be a bijection and to define $g: S_1 \times \mathbb{N} \to S_1 \cup S_2 \cup \cdots$ by $g(x,n)=f_n(x)$. I see that $g$ is a bijection.

So, the problem is reduced to "merely" proving that $|S_1 \times \mathbb{N}|=|S_1|$. I say "merely" with tongue in cheek because it is by no means obvious to me how to do it.

If $S_1$ is countable, I know how to proceed by the standard diagonal argument used to show $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable. But if $S_1$ is uncountable, I don't know what to do, even though it seems intuitive to me that crossing $S_1$ with $\mathbb{N}$ won't make the set "bigger" since it doesn't make it bigger in the countable case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be far simpler ways of doing this, but here's an idea. You could use the following theorem (which uses Zorn's lemma),

> **Theorem.** If $S$ is an infinite set, there exists a set $I$ and a collection $\{S_i\}_{i \in I}$ of disjoint, countably-infinite subsets of $S$ such that 
>   $$
> S = \bigsqcup_{i \in I}S_i.
> $$

A proof can be found in Kaplansky's *Set Theory and Metric Spaces*, Theorem 12, p.40. The idea of the proof is to consider the set of collections of countable disjoint subsets of $S$ with a certain order, so that (via Zorn's lemma) the maximal element of this set behaves as desired.

Now, by hypothesis we know that $S_1 = \bigsqcup_{j \in J}S_j$ with each $S_j$ a countable subset. Thus,

$$
S_1 \times \mathbb{N} = \bigsqcup_{j \in J} S_j \times \mathbb{N}
$$

Since $S_j$ is countable, we have $S_j \times \mathbb{N} \simeq \mathbb{N}^2 \simeq \mathbb{N} \simeq S_j$ where $\simeq$ denotes the existence of a bijection. This shows that

$$
S_1 \times \mathbb{N} = \bigsqcup_{j \in J} S_j \times \mathbb{N} \simeq \bigsqcup_{j \in J} S_j \simeq S_1.
$$

Comment: Are you sure AC is necessary for this? My intuition seems to say no? But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I am not sure. The theorem I quote sure uses Zorn's lemma in its proof, and I think Kaplansky uses this idea to show that $d^2 = d$ for infinite cardinals and moreover that $de = d$ if $e \leq d$, with $d$ infinite. This is a very specific subcase so it may be doable without AC (I should clarify that my knowledge of set theory is rather rudimentary).

Comment: Same as mine. My idea is to perhaps consider the set of injections from $\mathbb N$ to $S$, and try to partition $S$ via it. Perhaps since the naturals are more well behaved than arbitrary sets, I will have some lucky in finding a constructive partition.

Comment: Upon further study of the problem, I'm no longer confident of being able to do this sin Axiom of Choice. Every approach I take either requires some choice function, or some well-ordering on $S$.

Comment: @DonThousand It cannot be proven without choice: take infinite Dedekind finite set(which cannot inject into $\aleph_0$). In that case both the lemma here is false and the claim is false

Comment: @DonThousand Also note that without choice we can't move from $∪S_i$ to $S_i×\Bbb N$. For example: it is consistent that $\Bbb R$ is countable union of countable disjoint sets, but in ZF we have $\aleph_0^2=\aleph_0$

Comment: An intuitive way (IMO) under ZFC to prove the theorem you quoted is to note that every ordinal is of the form $\lambda + n$, with $\lambda$ limit and $n$ a natural number. Then the index set I can be all limit ordinals below the cardinality of S, and S_i is in bijection with $\{i, i+1, i+2, \ldots\} $.