# Does $|A\times \mathbb{Q}|=|\mathbb{R}|$ imply $|A|=|\mathbb{R}|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For any sets $A$ and $B$ let $|A|=|B|$, if there is bijection from $A$ to $B$. 
**My question is: Does $|A\times \mathbb{Q}|=|\mathbb{R}|$ imply $|A|=|\mathbb{R}|$?**

I began solving this problem by noticing that: $|A \times \mathbb{Q}|=|A \times \mathbb{Z}|$, since $|\mathbb{Q}|=|\mathbb{Z}|$.

Now we see that there is example of set $A$ satisfying the condition above - When ${A}=[0,1)$ it is clearly true that $|{A} \times \mathbb{Z}|=|\mathbb{R}|$ as we can find the following bijection: $f(x,n)=x+n, x \in {A} ~ n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and we also know that $|{A}|=|\mathbb{R}|$

I thought that maybe $|A \times \mathbb{Z}|=|B \times \mathbb{Z}|$ implies $|A|=|B|$ which would allow to solve the problem easily, but this unfortunately isn't true (For example when $A=\{1\}~ B=\{1,2\}$ )
Now I'm thinking about using some contradiction, but really I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: See "[Proving $|S \times \mathbb{N}| = |S|$ when $|S|$ is infinite.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3381015/proving-s-times-mathbbn-s-when-s-is-an-infinite-set?rq=1)"

Comment: Assuming the axiom of choice, yes. Without it, not necessarily.

Comment: $|A\times\mathbb{Q}|=\max(|A|,|\mathbb{Q}|)$

Comment: Ok thank you @Kolja I didn't noticed at the first sight that this solves my problem.